# Sending email from an AngularJS web application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, email

In one of my AngularJS web applications, I need to confirm a password by sending emails to a concerned person. How can I achieve this in AngularJS? I am a .NET guy and I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: You cannot send emails with an AngularJS app, you should send an AJAX request to your .NET server and the server will handle the rest.

Comment: Use webapi2 and create a AngularJS service to send an email, simply tie in the http service from angular and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have achieved through web services Please refer the code snippet below

```
public bool EmailNotification()
    {
            using (var mail = new MailMessage(emailFrom, "test.test.com"))
            {
                string body = "Your message : [Ipaddress]/Views/ForgotPassword.html";
                mail.Subject = "Forgot password";
                mail.Body = body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
                var smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailFrom, emailPwd);
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Send(mail);
                return true;
            }
    }
```

and ajax call as

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Service.asmx/EmailNotification",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data)
        {

        },
        error: function (XHR, errStatus, errorThrown) {
            var err = JSON.parse(XHR.responseText);
            errorMessage = err.Message;
            alert(errorMessage);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 9):

You might also look into using a third party SaaS, like Mandrill, SendGrid, or MailGun. I have worked w/ building in an email feature using Mandrill. Account is free to setup and threshold for billing on messaging is like 12k/month. Sending is just a matter of following their API to HTTP POST to their REST interface. Small example below:

```js
.controller('sentMailCntrl',function($scope, $http){
  $scope.sendMail = function(a){
    console.log(a.toEmail);
    var mailJSON ={
        "key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "message": {
          "html": ""+a.mailBody,
          "text": ""+a.mailBody,
          "subject": ""+a.subject,
          "from_email": "sender@sending.domain.com",
          "from_name": "Support",
          "to": [
            {
              "email": ""+a.toEmail,
              "name": "John Doe",
              "type": "to"
            }
          ],
          "important": false,
          "track_opens": null,
          "track_clicks": null,
          "auto_text": null,
          "auto_html": null,
          "inline_css": null,
          "url_strip_qs": null,
          "preserve_recipients": null,
          "view_content_link": null,
          "tracking_domain": null,
          "signing_domain": null,
          "return_path_domain": null
        },
        "async": false,
        "ip_pool": "Main Pool"
    };
    var apiURL = "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json";
    $http.post(apiURL, mailJSON).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert('successful email send.');
        $scope.form={};
        console.log('successful email send.');
        console.log('status: ' + status);
        console.log('data: ' + data);
        console.log('headers: ' + headers);
        console.log('config: ' + config);
      }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('error sending email.');
        console.log('status: ' + status);
      });
  }
})
```

Comment: Well, problem is the api key. If its available to angular its basically available to everyone. So I would not recommend this if you care about yourself :)

Comment: what if you wrote a PHP script that did that from your own server?

Answer (score 4):

you cannot send email via javascript library (angularjs or jquery and so on)
you need server side for send mail 
best way for this case use ajax

Answer (score 0):

```js
.controller('sentMailCntrl',function($scope, $http){
  $scope.sendMail = function(a){
    console.log(a.toEmail);
    var mailJSON ={
        "key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "message": {
          "html": ""+a.mailBody,
          "text": ""+a.mailBody,
          "subject": ""+a.subject,
          "from_email": "sender@sending.domain.com",
          "from_name": "Support",
          "to": [
            {
              "email": ""+a.toEmail,
              "name": "John Doe",
              "type": "to"
            }
          ],
          "important": false,
          "track_opens": null,
          "track_clicks": null,
          "auto_text": null,
          "auto_html": null,
          "inline_css": null,
          "url_strip_qs": null,
          "preserve_recipients": null,
          "view_content_link": null,
          "tracking_domain": null,
          "signing_domain": null,
          "return_path_domain": null
        },
        "async": false,
        "ip_pool": "Main Pool"
    };
    var apiURL = "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json";
    $http.post(apiURL, mailJSON).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert('successful email send.');
        $scope.form={};
        console.log('successful email send.');
        console.log('status: ' + status);
        console.log('data: ' + data);
        console.log('headers: ' + headers);
        console.log('config: ' + config);
      }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('error sending email.');
        console.log('status: ' + status);
      });
  }
})
```