# Sending email through Gmail API with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, gmail

I am trying to send an email through my angular controller. The user should be able to authenticate themselves via GMAIL and send emails through the web app.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with minimum `server-side` setup.
Have a look at this:

[Sending email from angularjs web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759686/sending-email-from-angular-js-web-application)

[Sending email with MEAN stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682461/how-do-you-send-emails-from-angular-controllers-on-the-mean-js-stack)